# throw and catch handling in php

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

Is there a way to throw an exception in PHP without try and catch?

I mean something like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['APIKEY']) || $_POST['APIKEY'] != API_KEY)
    throw new Exception(lang("apikey_error"));
```

Comment: Sure. But then you have an uncaught exception which terminates execution of your script with an ugly error message which is a poor way to do it.

Comment: Yes. It will be Unhandled exception if you don't have any catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much the whole point of exceptions is to ***not*** reflexively `catch` them.

Exceptions are an error handling mechanism that allows you to propagate errors. That explicitly means that if your application encounters an *exceptional* state in which it cannot continue working, you signal that by throwing an exception and abandoning the current execution context entirely. If this happens somewhere "at the top" of your application, the application is terminated, because it cannot continue to run. As it should.

Catching exceptions is for when your code is calling a subsystem and that code expects possible errors in that subsystem **and knows what to do with them.** The subsystem may fail, but the caller can deal with that failure. If the subsystem would be catching its own exceptions... what's the point?

```
try {
    throw new Exception;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // what now?
}
```

How does the above differ from the below?

```
// what now?
```

So, yes, you *can* and virtually always *should* throw exceptions without catching them right then and there. Leave the catching up to the caller.

```
function foo() {
    // Something's wrong, can't do my job, I'm outta here!
    throw new Exception;
}

try {
    foo();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // oh, something's wrong with foo(), let's try bar() instead
    bar();
}
```